# Uploading to amazon s3 while no internet android

Tags: java, android, networking, amazon-s3

Hello i just started to using AWS S3 and still getting familiar with the sdk for android.
i am intrested in the next scenario:
User tries to upload image but there is no internet connection, is there any way the api offers so the picture will be uploaded when the user opens the app some other time with internet connection. like upload eventualy when you get internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Store the pending uploads in data base or some where and You can listen the Network State changes through the broadcast receiver, When Internet Connection is available start your pending uploads through service.

Comment: Yes i know that but i was curious if there is some easier way allready implemnted